# How to assert whether a radio button is checked or not using Watir and Ruby?

Tags: ruby, radio-button, watir, watir-webdriver, assert

Let's assume I have the following HTML:

```
<form id='someForm'>
    <input type='radio' name='someName' value='option-1' />
    <input type='radio' name='someName' value='option-2' />
    <input type='radio' name='someName' value='option-3' checked='checked' />
    <input type='radio' name='someName' value='option-4' />
</form>
```

How can I use the watir-webdriver to assert that the 3rd option is checked? I can't seem to find anything online. I would imagine it's something like...

```
browser.input(:name => 'someName', :value => 'option-3').isChecked?
```

If any Watir experts could shine light on this that would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the [`set?`](http://rubydoc.info/gems/watir-webdriver/Watir/CheckBox#set?-instance_method) or `checked?` method:

```
browser.radio(:name => 'someName', :value => 'option-3').checked?
```

or

```
browser.radio(:name => 'someName', :value => 'option-3').set?
```

Since the element is a radio button, it is more clear if you use the `radio` instead of `input` method.

Comment: Thanks very much... WORKS!

Comment: If this solution worked, then please accept it as answer.  It helps keep SO tidy.

Comment: hey why cant we use value attribute here ,u have mentioned 'id' attribute instead of 'value' attribute.

Comment: @khan, I had based the answer on the html in the question at the time. If you check the edits, the html originally provided was using id instead of value attributes. I will change this answer to match the current question's html.

Answer (score 1):

U can check/unchecked the radio button using  'set' and 'clear' methods .Inorder to check whether the radiobutton is already checked or not just add '?' to the 'set' and 'checked' method 'set?' and 'checked?' which returns boolean value(true/false)

```
 browser.radio(:name => 'someName', :value => 'option-3').set?

 browser.radio(:name => 'someName', :value => 'option-3').checked?
```

so here the method set?,checked? returns the boolean value.